why dma_mapping_error return true in my program?
I have written a Linux kernel driver, I want to test dma API in Linux kernel, code:
I got "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." when I writting this question, so I write something useless to avoid this warning(can anyone help with this situation, My question is simple, and all I need is to paste it to this place.).
#define DEVICE_NAME "mychardev"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

static int major;
static char device_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
static struct cdev my_cdev;
static struct class *my_class;
static struct device *my_device;

static int my_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file) {
    return 0;
}

static int my_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file) {
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t my_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos) {
    return count;
}

static ssize_t my_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos) {
    return count;
}

static const struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = my_open,
    .release = my_release,
    .read = my_read,
    .write = my_write,
};

static int __init my_init(void) {
    int err;
    dev_t dev;
    unsigned char *tbuffer = NULL;
    dma_addr_t tbuffer_dma = 0;

    err = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, 0, 1, DEVICE_NAME);
    if (err < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "mychardev: Failed to allocate major number\n");
        return err;
    }

    major = MAJOR(dev);
    cdev_init(&my_cdev, &fops);
    my_cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;

    err = cdev_add(&my_cdev, dev, 1);
    if (err < 0) {
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, 1);
        printk(KERN_ERR "mychardev: Failed to add cdev\n");
        return err;
    }

    my_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, DEVICE_NAME);
    if (IS_ERR(my_class)) {
        cdev_del(&my_cdev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, 1);
        return PTR_ERR(my_class);
    }

    my_device = device_create(my_class, NULL, dev, NULL, DEVICE_NAME);
    if (IS_ERR(my_device)) {
        class_destroy(my_class);
        cdev_del(&my_cdev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, 1);
        return PTR_ERR(my_device);
    }

    tbuffer = (unsigned char *)kmalloc(1024 * 32 * sizeof(unsigned char), GFP_KERNEL | DMA_TO_DEVICE);
    if (!tbuffer) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "malloc failed\n");
        goto nomem;
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "kmalloc success\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "before map: %llx\n", tbuffer_dma);
    tbuffer_dma = dma_map_single(my_device, (void *)tbuffer, 64, DMA_TO_DEVICE);
    if (dma_mapping_error(my_device, tbuffer_dma)) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "dma map error\n");
    }
    memset(tbuffer, 0, 1024);
    print_hex_dump(KERN_INFO, "data:", DUMP_PREFIX_OFFSET, 32, 1, tbuffer, 1024, false);
    dma_sync_single_for_device(my_device, tbuffer_dma, 64, DMA_TO_DEVICE);
    printk(KERN_INFO "dma sync for device success\n");

    printk(KERN_INFO "dma addr is: %llx\n", tbuffer_dma);
    
    dma_unmap_single(my_device, tbuffer_dma, 1024, DMA_TO_DEVICE);

    kfree(tbuffer);

    printk(KERN_INFO "mychardev: Loaded with major number %d\n", major);
    return 0;

nomem:
    class_destroy(my_class);
    cdev_del(&my_cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(dev, 1);
    return -ENOMEM;
}

static void __exit my_exit(void) {
    device_destroy(my_class, MKDEV(major, 0));
    class_destroy(my_class);
    cdev_del(&my_cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(major, 0), 1);
    printk(KERN_INFO "mychardev: Unloaded\n");
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Your Name");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple character device driver");

After I built the driver, and insert .ko file to kernel using insmod command, I got error below:
dma map error

I have poor knowledge about dma, why would that happen?
I want to kown why dma_map_single failed. Thanks a lot.
